# Error with JQuery DataTables and ColVis plugin "Cannot read property 'sWidth' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Using the jquery.datatables plugin with the ColVis addon, I recieve this error when I remove a column:

"Cannot read property 'sWidth' of undefined".  I haven't been able to find a solution to this error online.

I'm not sure what's causing the error, although I do have a fix that I would like to post for the benefit of other's who run into this issue.

I'm using jquery.datatables 1.9.4 from http://datatables.net/.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I had this error when the number of columns in

```
<thead></thead>
```

was different from the number of columns in

```
$('#ls-table').DataTable($.extend({}, window.coonDataTableOptions, {
    columns: [
         <here>
    ]
 }));
```

Comment: In my case, I forgot to add extra { "data" : null }, { "data" : null } for my button edit and delete at the last column of each row

Answer (score 5):

On line 3255 of the DataTables source code is this line of code:

```
nThs[i].style.width = o.aoColumns[iVis].sWidth;
```

In this case o.aoColumns[iVis] is null because the column represented by the index has just been hidden.  It seems like I've run into a corner case that the creators of the plugins weren't expecting.  The above code gets called in response to an internal datatables event, which is triggered by a method called by ColVis when a column is hidden.  All that's needed to work around this is to change the above code to:

```
var column = o.aoColumns[iVis];

if(column != null) {
    nThs[i].style.width = o.aoColumns[iVis].sWidth;
}
```

unfortunately this requires editing the core plugin code, but I'll put in a bug report and hope that they resolve this soon.  in the meantime, hopefully this helps people looking for a workaround.

Comment: user1398619 shared the correct answer after I added mine.

Answer (score 3):

Such error occurs just due to populating columns within

...DataTable(...
"columns":...
)

mismatch with the defined HTML page Have number of columns.

..
..

Answer (score -2):

search  `a.aoColumns[D].sWidth` ,replace

```
 var column = a.aoColumns[D];if(column != null) {c.style.width=a.aoColumns[D].sWidth}
```